# Cover of $S^1$ such that their intersections are path connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I thinking about this problem when I try to compute the fundamental group of $S^1$ using Seifert-van Kampen Theorem.

There is a cover of at least two path connected opens
$U_{\alpha}$ of $S^1$ such that  All pairwise intersection are non-empty and path connected?

I think that such cover is impossible. But, I don't know how proof this.

Comment: Do you mean that all _pairwise_ intersections are non-empty and path connected? Or arbitrary intersections? Also, presumably you want to discount the open cover consisting of a single open set equal to the whole of $S^1$?

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: Try using three circle arcs.

Comment: Seeing that three circle arcs provides a trivial example, I would assume that you still want to refine your hypotheses? May I ask what motivated you to ask this question? That may help us to refine your hypotheses.

Comment: I like to show that any cover of $S^1$ satisfies the hypothesis of Seifert-van Kampen Theorem. Basically this

Comment: $S^1$ is a well known example not satisfying hypotheses of Seifert-van Kampen Theorem. See wiki on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem